# A problem occurred evaluating project ':ua_react-native-airship'. in React native

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing tis issue while running a react native project in android:

**A problem occurred evaluating project ':ua_react-native-airship'.

> react-native-airship: Failed to resolve 'react-native' in the project. If you have a non-standard project structure, you can specify 'reactNativeDir' with the path to 'react-native' in your 'gradle.properties' file.

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.**

*** Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':ua_react-native-airship'.
**

I am not able to figure out how to solve it? If anyone know how to solve it then please let me know.